# Oracle apex upload file doesn't upload on first action

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle12c, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an issue on first load of file upload. This simply don't load on first option. I'm testing on https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=65673:3 user and pwd test.
I create a blank page, with a file_browse field, P3_ARQUIVO, and a IR region for displaying the results of temp files loads.
Configured the storage type as apex_application_temp_files on :P3_ARQUIVO.
As the session doesn't capture the value of file_browse field, I changed my submit create process to insert on table with a created_by argurment, with a cursor, to multiple loading actions. This working fine. But the problem at file browse,  which does not load the first action.

Anybody could help on this?

This script below is only for purpose of analisys and reviews. Its working fine, on create button dynamic action:

```
declare
    CURSOR cursorArquivos is 
    select filename AS FILENAME,mime_Type AS MIME_TYPE, last_updated as LAST_UPDATED, blob_content as BLOB_CONTENT 
from apex_application_files
where CREATED_BY = :APP_USER; 
    linhaArquivos cursorArquivos%rowtype;
begin



      OPEN cursorArquivos;
         LOOP
          FETCH cursorArquivos INTO linhaArquivos;
           EXIT WHEN cursorArquivos%NOTFOUND ;
             insert into TESTE (CAMPOA, CAMPOB, CAMPOG, CAMPOH) values (linhaArquivos.filename, linhaArquivos.mime_Type,linhaArquivos.LAST_UPDATED, linhaArquivos.blob_content);
          END LOOP ;

       CLOSE cursorArquivos;
       delete from apex_application_files
where CREATED_BY = :APP_USER;

     COMMIT;

     EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         NULL;
end;
```

Comment: provide username to your test application

Comment: Hi, user: test password: test

Comment: If you have storage type as apex_application_temp_files than your IR should also be on the same table. Also you need to know, that the uploaded files are deleted at end of session or end of request (depends on what you selected in the Item file browse). Request => after submit => you can't see the uploaded file in the report, because it has been purged.

Comment: Hi Sara, I'm basically informed about these questions. I created two IR, one using the apex_application_files, which shows the previous insert, after an ajax no_data error, and a second one, for   from apex_application_temp_files, that shows nothing. The data is pushed on apex_applications_files, but oddly delayed. The first upload are retrieved on second upload action, the second, on the third, and so on...